# 8086 Assemnly , 65535 and -1

Tags: assembly, bit, x86-16

**65535 = 0xffff(unsigned)**
**-1 = 0xffff(signed)**
In my bochsgdb
`mov ax , 65535` and `mov ax , -1` can change the content in AX to 11111111
I don't know why it has the same effect.
If in this way . How does 8086 assembly distinguish between -1 and 65535 ? and How do I know the bits are represented for unsigned or signed ?

I thy to google but I did not get the answer , I wish you can explain why is this ? please

Comment: It's all how you interpret the bits. Some operations treat the bits as unsigned, some as signed. For the case of setting a register there's really no practical difference.

Comment: "How do I know the bits are represented for unsigned or signed " -- the same way the processor knows: the program says so by the choice of instructions used, whenever it matters.

Comment: -1 and 65535 are the same number. Ever played blackjack? An ace can be a 1 or an 11 depending on what you want it to be at any given moment. It's like that.